# use loop to return blog details

Tags: php, functions, loop

I want to return information about a blog. It could be, author name, title, date, country whatever just to test.

```
<?php
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    while ($post_id != 0) 
        {
            $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
            $author_id = $queried_post->post_author;
            echo get_the_author_meta('display_name',$author_id);
            $post_id++;
        }
?>
```

In the following code, I'm trying to get all the author's name between post_id 20 to 25. When the code is run, it only displays:

```
The author is: 
The author is: 
The author is: 
The author is: 
The author is: 
The author is:
```

Can you tell me how i would fix it so that it would return any kind of information about the blog (in this case, the name of the author).

**THE UPDATED CODE DOESN'T DISPLAY ANYTHING.**

Comment: `The author is: <?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ); ?>` - do you have something like that in your code? Or maybe `echo 'The author is: ' . get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id );` ? And if you're in the standard Loop (`while ( have_posts() ) ...`), you wouldn't need to specify the second parameter there (the `$author_id` - i.e. the user ID).

Comment: @SallyCJ how would i return $post_id using that code? $author_id = $queried_post->post_id; Did that but nothing. –

Comment: I'm sure you already have the answer by now, @Jpatel. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-arrange your code.

```
<?php 
        $post_id = 20;

        while($post_id <= 25) {
            $queried_post = get_post($post_id); 

            $author_id = $queried_post->post_author;
            echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id);


            $post_id++;
        } 
?>
```

Within `while` loop above you have `$queried_post` which is an object of class [`WP_Post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post). [Member Variables of WP_Post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post#Member_Variables_of_WP_Post) can be used to display data about each post.

I hope this may help.

**UPDATE**

> what if i want to the loop to apply to all of the post that there are on the site. What would be the changes i would need to make in order for me to apply to all the posts?

In that case you may code like that using [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) which returns an array of  objects

```
<?php 
        $arg = array( 'numberposts' => -1 );  // get all posts

        $queried_posts = get_posts( $arg);

        // Now loop through $queried_posts
        foreach( $queried_posts as $queried_post ) {

            $author_id = $queried_post->post_author;
            echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id);

        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Hey @Qaisar, In the above code, yk how we r getting only post_id's from 20 to 25. what if i want to the loop to apply to all of the post that there are on the site. What would be the changes i would need to make in order for me to apply to all the posts?

Comment: u can check my code and tell me what I need to do. I'm editing the home.php file and i don't know if it would effect all the blog posts.

Comment: @Jpatel in that case you can use [get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) and loop through posts using `foreach` . There are many [examples](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#user-contributed-notes) that may help you.

Comment: @Jpatel please see the updated answer

Comment: how would i return $post_id using that code? $author_id = $queried_post->post_id; Did that but nothing.

Comment: @Jpatel `$queried_post->ID` will give you post's id. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post#Member_Variables_of_WP_Post) list of member variables of `WP_Post` object.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to get the author name inside the loop. Once your inside the loop you will be dealing with one post at a time, then you can access any post info you need.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post

**Qaisar has it right for your while loop. Inside the loop you have to get the post. 
 $queried_post = get_post($post_id); 
then you can get the author...

UPDATED AGAIN

```
<?php

    $args = [
    'post__in' => range( 20, 25 ), //**get post in your range**
    ];
    $queried_posts= get_posts( $args ); // **now you have the post you want**

    foreach( $queried_posts as $queried_post ) {  // **loop through**
        $author_id = $queried_post->post_author;
        echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id) .'</br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Check updated code

Comment: @J.Bigham `$author_id = $post->post_author;` will not work properly without `setup_postdata( $post );`.  On first line you missed `;` .

Comment: good catch @Qaisar! I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @J.Bigham can you please help me? I've updated my code.

Comment: Are you still not seeing results? It looks like you removed the hard coded  $post_id = 20;

Comment: @Jpatel let me know if your having issues still

Comment: @J.Bigham Yes ur code fixed the problem but I need to return post_id using foreach loop. How would i do that/

Comment: @Jpatel I update the code to the for each loop. by supplying parameters to the get_posts() function you can filter out unwanted posts. https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts  Then all your posts will be stored in the variable $queried_posts and you will be able to loop through with a foreach loop.